# Does "but" start a main clause or subclause?

Tags: grammar, coordination

Which is the main clause in this sentence?

> The car may have been past its prime, but it still turns heads wherever it goes.

Before the comma, "the car may have been past its prime", or after the comma "it still turns heads wherever it goes"? And how can I tell in general?

Comment: _But_ means the same thing as _and_. The only difference is a presupposition of surprise with _but_; the meaning's the same. So if _and_ can start a main clause, so can _but_.

Comment: @JohnLawler can _and_ start a main clause? When can _and_ start a main clause?

Comment: It's a coordination of two main clauses. An example with "and": [It was a perfect day] and [everyone was in good spirits].

Comment: @JohnLawler Why was this migrated to ELL? There's nothing here that indicates it's about learning English. A native speaker or anybody curious about the linguistics of English might ask this question, even if it is simple. I ask in particular because in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/327840/which-is-the-main-clause-and-which-the-subclause-in-as-so-sentences) from the same user, I recommended they take it to EL&U because it's not strictly about learning English, and EL&U has more linguists.

Comment: @gotube I don't know why it was migrated. I'm not an authority. This is first-grade grammar, and you don't need more linguists (which, frankly, we don't have in ELU anyway) for first-grade grammar. They're more patient with slow learners here in ELL.

Answer (score 4):

Your assumption that one of those is the "main" clause and the other a "subordinate" clause is incorrect.

Your sentence joins together two independent clauses via a standard coördinating conjunction.  One clause does not command, control, or govern the other in any way.

[Collins](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/easy-learning/what-are-subordinating-clauses-in-english) explains this to beginners in this way:

> When two or more clauses are joined by a conjunction **other than *and*, *but*, *or*, or *yet***, one of the clauses is the main clause; the other clauses are subordinate clauses.

You simply have two coördinated clauses here. They are two separate and complete sentences in the grammatical sense.

1. The car may have been past its prime.
2. It still turns heads wherever it goes.

If you want a subordinate clause, you need a subordinating conjunction not a coördinating one:

> Although the car may have been past its prime, it still turns heads wherever it goes.

Now you have one of each. Before you did not.

Comment: if "The car may have been past its prime, but it still turns heads wherever it goes" were parsed into a syntax tree, which clause would be at a higher level?

Comment: Which is the main clause and subclause in sentences conjoined by "as" ? "They spoke as they ate", "As they ate they spoke", "As their food disappeared, so did their  hunger" . I put up a question asking this too: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/327840/29750

Answer (score 2):

"But" joins two independent clauses, as it is  a coordinating conjunction.  In general, it grammatically functions exactly like "and" in that function.